# How to connect to individual google spreadsheet with Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-sheets, google-api

I'm a Flutter beginner.
I'm currently developing an app in Flutter and implemented Google Sign In using Firebase.
So now I want to save the data in the google spreadsheet for each signed-in account.
In the method using gsheet, only the one that saves the data in the sheet of the individual application developer (me) comes out.

The question is

1. How to upload data to each google spreadsheet of the signed-in account
2. Alternatively, how to make the signed-in account create a new google spreadsheet in the app and access it

I would like to ask you about the above two points.